# Difference between raw and parameterized Optional when invoking orElseGet(Supplier)

Tags: java, exception, optional-parameters, optional-chaining

Consider the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
             // throws Exception // line 1 
    {
        Optional empty1 = Optional.empty(); // line 2
        Optional<Object> empty2 = Optional.empty(); // line 3

        Optional.empty().orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Empty optional")); // line 4
        empty1.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Empty optional")); // line 5
        empty2.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Empty optional")); // line 6
    }

}
```

- When line 1 is commented, then line 4, 5, 6 all report compile-time errors:

  - Line 4 and 6: **Unhandled exception: java.lang.Exception**
  - Line 5: **Unhandled exception: java.lang.Throwable**
    This makes me feel that line 4 is called with type parameter as `<Object>` like line 6, but what makes the differences on the exact exception thrown?
- When line 1 is uncommented, then only line 5 reports compile-time error: **Unhandled exception: java.lang.Throwable**. It will be solved if I change line 1 to **throws Throwable**. Why throwing **Exception** is not enough for line 5 to resolve compile-time error?

Comment: [generics - why doesn't Optional orElseThrow compile?](https://coderanch.com/t/747790/java/generics-doesn-Optional-orElseThrow-compile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is due to the use of raw types in Java. Method signature of orElseThrow is:

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X
```

So, for case in line 2 and 5 you have:

```
Optional empty1 = Optional.empty(); // line 2
empty1.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Empty optional")); // line 5
```

in above `orElseThrow` signature case compiler is not provided with `T` type and even thought it has `X`, it will generate raw call. It will substitute X with its upperbound which is Throwable, and T will be Object. The result is:

```
public Object orElseThrow(Supplier exceptionSupplier) throws Throwable
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

thus, compiler reports:

```
error: unreported exception Throwable
```

The case of:

```
Optional.empty().orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Empty optional")); // line 4
```

is more interesting, here no explicit type is specified, but compiler reports error of `Exception` being thrown. So its different from the previous case. You again must look at the signature of the used function, in this case Optional.empty():

```
public static<T> Optional<T> empty()
             ^^^ ~~~ type inference
```

The important part is `<T>` which indicate that it will infer its type `T` from the enclosing context. In `line 4` compiler is unable to infer type, and uses `Object` type instead. I believe in JLS its stated here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.1.3

> If Pl has no TypeBound, the bound αl <: Object appears in the set.

and also in oracle tutorial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

> The compiler requires a value for the type argument T so it starts
> with the value Object. Consequently, the invocation of
> Collections.emptyList returns a value of type List<Object>

The important thing, is that in `line 4` you are not dealing with raw types like in lines 2 and 5, but with generic ones (generic type `T` is `Object`), so when orElseThrow is called, its signature is

```
public Object orElseThrow(Supplier exceptionSupplier) throws Exception
```

both generic types `T` nad `X` are known, so generic function call is generated, which in the end causes in your example this compiler error:

error: unreported exception Exception;

Now, line 3 and 6, is explicitly using generic type Object, and this makes the signature of orElseThrow as previously:

```
public Object orElseThrow(Supplier exceptionSupplier) throws Exception
```

which gives the same error:

error: unreported exception Exception;